# TimeOff Script failures and incorrect formatting

Tags: google-apps-script

[google-apps-script] I'm having issues with the TimeOff Script. I get failures after every submit but cannot find what's causing them, I the spreadsheet isn't properly reporting into the correct row, the event on the calendar isn't in the correct time. This is Where I found the script initially.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/vacation-requests

Comment: Describe your failures.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to make a proper question.

Comment: Summary of failures that I get in an email is always "onFormSubmit Please select an active sheet first. (line 291, file "Code")" but I have an active sheet that the info is going to from the form. So I'm unclear as to where/whatsheet I'm supposed to be selecting. Issue #2 - the row on the sheet that's populated from the form, when "approved" and then I "notify employees" it is creating the event/auto changing the notified status to "Notified" for the row above what I am actually approving.

Comment: Issue #3 - When the calendar event is created, then event is put on the wrong day. I fixed they by requiring a time to be entered for the time off start and stop. However, on the calendar the actual event is scheduled and hour before it is actually supposed to start.

Comment: @ChrisWedel I followed the instructions on the example showed on the [Manage employee vacation time requests](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/vacation-requests) and it's working as intended for me. In your "#2 issue" what do you want to do with that? What is your intended behaviour for that case? In your "3# issue", for how many days, the event misses being created on the correct day?

Comment: @albertovielma for #2 I'd like the row that I approve to add the event and notification for the same row that I'm on. If a request is made and is on row 2 of the sheet and I approve and then notify employees, the event doesn't go on a calendar, the notification email doesn't go out, and the notified status doesn't change. Once a request comes through on row 3 and I go through the approval process for row 3, only then does row 2 get the event created, notification email go out, and the notified status change. Now I'm left with row 3 not processed.

Comment: @albertovielma on #3 the event, if I don't require a time of day to be specified in the request, will be on the calendar 1 day early instead of the actual day requested. However, the description is correct for the event. If I do require time to be input on the request the even will go on the correct day however the times of the event are early by 1 hour. I live in CST and it seems it puts the time zone for GMT.

Comment: I'm still having issues being able to get the row that I approve to add the event to the calendar or send the notification email. Example is when approving row 1 as the first request, nothing happens in terms of calendar or email. When approving row 2 request, an event and email goes out for row 1 not 2. I have changed none of the script aside from manager email.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1)

Your first issue is most likely you don't have a sheet linked to your form. To know if a sheet is linked to the form, it must have this icon:

[image]

A form will be linked when you click on ***TimeOff -> Form Setup***

#### 2)

Your second issue about not getting the mail is because you probably didn't change the hardcoded email in 48 code line:

```js
/** TODO: Hard code your manager's email */
var MANAGER_EMAIL = 'yoyomade@google.com';
```

To open the script, go to ***Tools -> Script Editor***.

#### 3)

Your third issue happens because the event is created with the default `MANAGER_EMAIL`'s time.

---

### DOCS

For more info check:

- [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar)
- [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail)

Comment: Thank you for the help. On #1 - It's attached because when I enter the info on the form it sends it to the sheet. The error I get about the active sheet occurs when I approve/notify employees on the sheet. #2 - I have changed line 48, the issue is that the action for replying to the employee email and adding to the calendar on approval happens for the row above the line being approve. Request is on line 2, if I approve and notify no email goes out and no cal. Request comes in on line 3, if I approve and notify then the email and cal event happens for line 2...not 3.

Comment: Do you make any changes to the code? If you did, please provide them in your post, it will be easier to understand what you mean

Comment: I have tried, but even when I create a form from start/scratch I get the issue #2 & #3. The only change I made to start was the manager email. Is there a place to share what my code looks like?

Comment: here is the sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NxP9KrldMeFTIl1xyTWPvK1Md42eqq_mILtsuD9e3gc/edit?usp=sharing  if you'd like to take a peek at what I'm dealing with.

Comment: you can put your code in your question and format it like it says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Thank you for sharing the link, but I can't see the code if I don't have edit permissions

Comment: I have given permiissions

Comment: I have notice there are several domains like ***@gmail.com*** and for example ***@example.com***. When I was testing it, it was from the same domain, get a new copy from example page and try it using accounts from the same domain

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by using accounts from the same domain.

Comment: You use user-email@onegas.com and user-email@gmail.com, that's what I mean by different domains

Comment: Gotcha, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I just tried it from scratch and used @gmail.com for everything and it still doesn't action on the correct row. I submitted a request from the newly created form, it showed up on to the sheet. When I approved the request and then went to notified employees, no email was sent to the requesting email and no calendar event was created. Also the notified status didn't change. The only part of the script I changed was the manager email.